# Ruby on Rails + Devise + Existing User Table == No confirm_tokens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, confirmation

I have a new rails system I am creating.  I am in the process of setting up devise for authentication.  My issue is that all my existing users do not have confirm tokens, and I can't figure out a way to get the tokens to them.  I had expected that upon login the user would be prompted to resend the token but this isn't the case.  Furthermore, I can't figure out how to alter the authentication process to add this link when the user successfully authenticates.

I'd like to alter it so they can login for a certain time period but they are presented with a link to resend confirmation before the time period expires.  I saw that there is a way to set the time period they are able to login for, but I can't figure out where that configuration is.  I'm also concerned that since they don't have a confirm_token at all in the database it won't do much good.

Comment: I found the setting for confirm_within it's under config/initializers/devise.rb

I'm not sure if this is where I should set it or if I should try and set it in an environment file somewhere.

However, it doesn't work for me.  I'm assuming it's because there is no confirm_token for the user.

But hopefully this will help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the confirmable option of devise. Here you have to do two things. First you have to set the time period that you allow to answer the confirm.

To set the time period that the user has to confirm you have to configure the devise initializer and uncomment one line:

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.confirm_within = 2.days
```

Next you have to send the confirmation mail manually (this function will also create the confirmation token if it doesn't exist), this can be done by console or in a script:

```
# in console
User.find(1).send_confirmation_instructions
```

I would test that and then write the following script:

```
# script.rb
User.all.each do |user|
  user.send_confirmation_instructions
end
```

That is a very slow process if you have thousands of users but will do the job.

Check it out: [Confirmable](http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable)

Comment: That is enabled but that's not the token I am talking about.  I'm talking about the confirmation after a user registers.  Existing users will not have a confirmation token and they will not be able to log in.  If I try and set a time period in which they can log in without confirmation it doesn't work.  So I'm at a loss as to how I can create confirmation_tokens for them and at the same time notify them that they need to confirm their account.

Comment: I misunderstood the question the first time... I fixed my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Just confirm your existing users like so

```
User.all.each do |user| user.confirm! end
```

in the console or in a script.

Comment: Don't think he wanted to automatically confirm all users. I think he wanted them to have to confirm their emails.